# How to typedef a template with a default constructor argument

Tags: c++, typedef

I'm attempting to typedef a template class to accept a default constructor argument but I'm running into an error.

This works fine:

```
typedef TransientWriter<DDS::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaData,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataTypeSupport_var,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataTypeSupportImpl,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataWriter,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataWriter_var,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataReader,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataReader_var> Writer;
```

However, I want this class to take a default string parameter through the constructor. I've tried:

```
typedef TransientWriter<DDS::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaData,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataTypeSupport_var,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataTypeSupportImpl,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataWriter,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataWriter_var,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataReader,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataReader_var>
(::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataTopic) Writer;
```

Which gives me a cranky error: `error: expected initializer before ‘Writer’`

And I've also tried this:

```
typedef TransientWriter<DDS::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaData,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataTypeSupport_var,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataTypeSupportImpl,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataWriter,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataWriter_var,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataReader,
::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataReader_var>
Writer(::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataTopic);
```

which gives me `error: typedef ‘JARSS::DDS::Object::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaData::Writer’ is initialized (use decltype instead)`

Am I going about this typedef all wrong? Are there any suggestions for what I could do instead?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. `typedef` only sets an alias for types, it doesn't pass parameters to constructors.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think it could.

Comment: Are you trying to use the typedef to specify which constructor to be used? The compiler should figure that out when you actually get around to passing the parameter in.

Comment: No I'm trying to explicitly set the constructor input in the typedef. There is only one constructor for type `TransientWriter(const std::string topic = "")`. I just wanted to ensure that the correct topic string was being used.

Comment: @TylerJandreau if you want to impose that constraint, it will be better to have a constructor that takes no arguments and make sure that you initialize your member with the right value.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this in C++.

Consider creating a new class, adding an overload to the constructor of `TransientWriter<DDS::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaData, ::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataTypeSupport_var, ::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataTypeSupportImpl, ::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataWriter, ::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataWriter_var, ::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataReader, ::NetAcquire::MeasurandMetaDataDataReader_var>` or creating a factory function.

Comment: I didn't think so either, just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to abuse `typedef` in order to create what is essentially a new class declaration -- one with a constructor that didn't exist in the class that is being `typedef`ed from.

You can't do that because that's not really what `typedef` does.  It's true that `typedef` creates a unique type -- but that unique type is really just an *alias* for some other type.  A nickname, if you will.

`typedef` also doesn't translate in to code that executes.  That is, there's no `typedef` *function* that gets called.  It's really just creating an alias.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your description in the comments section, you are trying to do something like:

```
struct A
{
   A(int a) : data(a) {}
};

typedef A (10) MyA;
```

Instead, you could change `A` to:

```
struct A
{
   A() : data(10) {}
};
```

If you are not able to modify `A`, create a sub-class that initializes `A` with what you need it to be:

```
struct A
{
   A(int a) : data(a) {}
};

struct MyA : public A
{
    MyA() : A(10) {}
};
```